# SQLite3 Using conditions in Triggers between BEGIN & END

Tags: android, triggers, sqlite

I am trying to create the following trigger but it says:

> Error while creating trigger: near "INSERT": syntax error Unable to execute statement.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig2
   AFTER 
   UPDATE OF flag
   ON table1
   FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    SELECT CASE flag
    WHEN 1 THEN 
        INSERT OR IGNORE INTO stats VALUES(NEW.id,CURRENT_DATE,0);
    ELSE
        DELETE FROM stats WHERE app_id=NEW.id AND ondate=CURRENT_DATE and runtime=0;
    END;
END;
```

What I want to do is:

- when `flag=1` in **table1:**
   
  **insert a new row** in **stats** if the record doesn't already exist for same **id** and **ondate**.
- when `flag=0`**:**
  **delete record from stats** with the following constraint:
  `WHERE app_id=NEW.id AND ondate=CURRENT_DATE and runtime=0;`

I can't figure out what is wrong near "INSERT" please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a syntax error as according to the [Syntax Diagram](http://www.sqlite.org/images/syntax/create-trigger-stmt.gif) for SQLite Triggers we can't have any **IF** or **CASE** clause between **BEGIN** and **END**.

So you should create ***two triggers*** for different operations like this:

**1) For Delete Case**

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig1
   AFTER 
   UPDATE OF flag
   ON table1
   FOR EACH ROW 
   WHEN NEW.flag=0
  BEGIN
     DELETE FROM stats WHERE app_id=NEW.id AND ondate=CURRENT_DATE and runtime=0;
  END;
```

**2) For Insert Case**

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig2
   AFTER 
   UPDATE OF flag
   ON table1
   FOR EACH ROW 
   WHEN NEW.flag=1
 BEGIN     
    INSERT OR IGNORE INTO stats VALUES(NEW.id,CURRENT_DATE,0);  
 END;
```

Comment: Hey I Update the answer now try this way

Comment: yes I've just figured out the same. now I've created two triggers and everything is working fine. :) thanks